# Could not transfer artifact org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:zip:1.11 from/to mavenCentral

Tags: grails, dependencies

While running my project in spring suit tool i am getting this error

resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:zip:1.11 from/to mavenCentral (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): repo1.maven.org (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Could not transfer artifact org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:zip:1.11 from/to mavenCentral (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): repo1.maven.org

Can anyone help me to overcome this in STS?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying an extension:

build(group: 'org.fusesource.jansi', name: 'jansi', version: '1.11', extension: 'pom')